# How do I deploy an ADF business component?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

How do I deploy an ADF business component to the middle tier and call it using [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)?

I just cannot find any good documentation on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the ADF BC application module and use your right button to create a business components deployment and select [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean) session bean. This will create different [EAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) files
which you can deploy. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like:

- *[How to install ADF 10 runtime and deploy ADF BC app to Oracle WebLogic 103 running on Linux](http://blog.fekw.de/2008/08/23/howto-install-adf-10-runtime-and-deploy-adf-bc-app-to-oracle-weblogic-103-running-on-linux/)*
- *[Oracle Application Development Framework - Development Guidelines (10g)](http://docushare.sf.adfg.state.ak.us/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-16186/Oracle+Application+Development+Framework+-+Development+Guidelines+%2810g%29.pdf)* (PDF format).

Comment: unfortunately I have ran across those and they were not helpful. However at this point this question is answered. Now to find out how to call it using RMI.